# Why is the prompt not working in my function?

Tags: javascript

I think I have done everything right, but for some reason, the code is not working.

```
function checkDriverAge() {
    var age = prompt("What is your age?");
    if (Number(age) < 18) {
        alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
    } else if (Number(age) > 18) {
        alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
    } else if (Number(age) === 18) {
        alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: @insyri the code clearly converts the string returned by `prompt()` into a number.

Comment: Also how exactly is `checkDriverAge()` being called?

Comment: Could be any reason, like the optional `type` attribute of your `<script>` tag having a typo. [Edit] the post and provide a [mre]. See [How to create Stack Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is full code then I think you forgot to run this function somewhere. For example, If I run this code on page load then it works 100%:

```
// insert this code into html file
<script>

(function() {
   var age = prompt("What is your age?");
    if (Number(age) < 18) {
        alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
    } else if (Number(age) > 18) {
        alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
    } else if (Number(age) === 18) {
        alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
    }

})();
</script>
```